# How can I open a function's documentation in the REPL?

Tags: racket

Is there a way to get a function's documentation on DrRacket's REPL? E.g. something like:

```
(doc somefunction)
```

The [documentation](http://racket-lang.org/help.html) only mentions "external" resources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to open documentation.

- **In the Racket REPL**, type `(help id)` to get help for a particular identifier.

  The `help` binding is provided from the `racket/help` library, which is loaded at startup by default by the `racket` executable when started in interactive mode with no other command-lin arguments. It is *not* available by default in DrRacket. If it is unavailable, but you want to use it, just type `(require racket/help)` to import it first.
- **If [XREPL](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html) is loaded**, you can also type `,doc id` to get help.

  To load XREPL, use `(require xrepl)` in the REPL. For more information, including information on loading XREPL by default, see [its documentation](http://docs.racket-lang.org/xrepl/index.html).
- **In DrRacket**, right-click an identifier and click "show documentation", or just press F1.
- **From the command-line**, use `raco docs query ...` to search through the help index.

Answer (score 0):

Documentation Search (http://docs.racket-lang.org/raco/docs.html)

Command-line flags:
Use `-h` or `--help` — show help information for this command